# How do I get the webpack publicPath

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using the following code add icons to the MdIconRegistry:

```
constructor(iconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  iconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(
    sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/svg-sprite-action-symbol.svg'));
  iconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(
    sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/svg-sprite-content-symbol.svg'));
  iconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(
    sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/svg-sprite-navigation-symbol.svg'));
}
```

This unfortunately breaks when using `ng [build|serve] --deploy-url=/public/`  (In production I would like to deploy the `ng build` output to a CDN)

Is there a way that I can access the webpack publicPath variable from my angular component so that I can specify the urls for the svg icons relative to that?

I had a look in the `ng build` output, and I can see the variable is set in `inline.bundle.js`, but I'm not sure how to correctly access it.

```
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "/public/";
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is supposed to be available to the app at all. A cleaner way is to expose it as environment variable, I guess.

Comment: You can look at this post https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/. Probably what you want.

Comment: Petr TIchy did a good video series on Youtube. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkEZWD8wbltnRp6nRR8kv97RbpcUdNawY  Here's a sample of his webpack.config.js including Twitter Bootstrap. You can see from this how he is dealing with images. https://github.com/Ihatetomatoes/webpack-101-bootstrap/blob/master/webpack.config.js Sometimes the syntax evolves with this stuff - so be sure to refer to the https://webpack.js.org/ website too

Answer (score 4):

You can get it from `__webpack_public_path__` global variable.

Answer (score 3):

if you have access to `webpack-configration file` then you can easely get the public path

suppose you have `webpack.config.js` in your project root and you have component file in `/src/component/mycomponent.js`

and your webpack.config.js is something like this

```
module.exports = {
.
.
.
 output: {
   path: "somthing",
   filename: "somthing",
   publicPath: "something"
 }
.
.
.
}
```

then `/src/component/mycomponent.js` would be like

```
import webpackConfig from "../../webpack.config"

const publickPath = webpackConfig.output.publicPath
```

webpack config file is just like another javascript file you can import content from it